# Generalization of $\alpha + \beta + \gamma = 180°$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

It's well known to me that the sequence of $N$ line segments in $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be a closed loop only if the sum of angles between neighboring segments is equal to $(N-2)*180°$.

By analogy, in order to define a sequence of $N$ line segments in $\mathbb{R}^3$ one must use $2N$ values, for example, $N$ angles just like in the case of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $N$ dihedral angles (see definition on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_angle)).

My question: Is there any explicit way to express the condition of closed loop of $N$ linear segments in $\mathbb{R}^3$ as a relation between $2N$ angles?

Comment: About the claim in your first sentence: "only if", yes, perhaps, if you are careful with your signs. But I don't think the "if" part can be true.

Comment: Thank you for the response!
Yes, you are absolutely right. My correntions to the question:
case of R^2: for any N values of angles with the sum equal to (N-2)*180 the loop can be closed for some values of lengths of line segments.

case of R^3: Is there any condition X such that for any 2*N values of angles obeying X the loop can be closed for some values of lengths of line segments?

Comment: You should edit those corrections into your question.

Comment: I am almost certain that no such condition exist. Besides, it is clear that the closing condition is equivalent to the fact that the 3 projections of your 3D segments on coordinates' planes $xOy,yOz,zOx$ are closed, i.e., easily verifiable facts.